# Create Quiz App Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm writing a quiz app in ASP.NET and I need to determine if for each question I need to use radio button for single correct answer or check box for multiple correct answer.

What is the simple and better way to do this?

I'll be using simple SQL for database. I have a current tables:

```
question table:
questionid, questiondesc, ismultiple (to determine radio or checkbox)

answer table:
questionid, answerid, answerdesc, iscorrect
```

I also need to check the correct answer upon submission.

Comment: If there are multiple answers you can use checkboxes If there is only 1 answer which can be right you can use radio

Comment: Hi @MikeLammers, Yes Bro that's what I need, do you have a sample code? Thanks.

Comment: First write your own code, if it goes wrong after you do that. Ask your question on StackOverflow. If you already have code, please add it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is **easier** to use a RadioButton since processing a single answer is easier than multiple in the most cases. But this doesn't mean it's the best option, if you have questions which are (according to you) better off with multiple answers you should probably use checkboxes.

Another thing, if you would choose to go for the checkboxes you would probably have to make a table for the answers with a foreign key to the question since one question has one or multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

ismultiple flag in your question table will help you to decide which control
    to use at runtime(i.e radio or checkbox). use control accordingly.

Use tables like:

```
Question => questionid,  question_statement,  ismultiple
Options  => optionid, questionid(FK), option_statement
answers  => answerid, questionid(FK_Question), optionid(FK_option)
```

This is the simplest database structure for your problem.
     you can add more columns if you need. 
    ismultiple flag will help you to know how many records to fetch from answer table for 
    particular question (i.e single or multiple correct answer).